# Passing Id in user model

Tags: laravel

I have something like this,

```
public function hasAlreadyScoredVideo($video_id){
return $this->scoresheet()->where('video_id', $video_id)- 
 >count() > 0
 }
```

How do i pass the $video_id? I am using hasMany relationship.

Comment: what is the `hasMany` relationship name ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question, but instead `->count() > 0` you can use - `->exists()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your Models exactly, but it could be handled by a anonymous function in a `whereHas`. Just check want you need instead of `scoresheet.video`.

```
public function hasAlreadyScoredVideo($video_id){
    return $this->scoresheet()->whereHas('scoresheet.video', function($q, $video_id) {
        $q->where('id', $video_id);
    })->get();
}
```